# Internet Explorer DOM7009: Unable to decode image at URL: Mime type "image/webp"

Tags: image, internet-explorer, firefox, webpack, mime-types

I'm using a webpack image loader to import images and use them across my scss or js files.

The thing is, images are rended in Chrome but not on Firefox or IE.

On IE Edge I get the following error:

[image: enter code here]

As my network tab shows the mime type of the image is image/jpg

[image]

And this is the response from the server.

[image]

But the images are not rendered

[image]

Anyone knows why this error is happening? I guess that it's not rendered on Firefox for the same reasons but I don't know how I can fix this. It's also happening in embedded images like:

data:image/png;Base64, .....

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I realized that the causing of this problem was my webpack image-loader configuration. I was using webp option and thus enabling webp conversion of all images but without changing image extension. I disabled that option and all images are showing again.